Fixed timestep without cloning game state
I'm doing a JS game with hundreds of moving physical particles.
I've read the famous "fix your timestep" article. So far I've implemented basic prototype with janky game loop tied to FPS and it works fine.
Now, I want to use a proper fixed timestep. I've chosen fixed because I really don't like doing * deltaTime on my kinda physics simulations, also I want potential multiplayer, time controls and tests.
I'm worried about several things:

I've realized that Gaffer's article requires me to essentially copy my game state every physics update, which, in the article, is (strangely) copied by: previousState = currentState; If I'm wrong and it's not copied, then it's strange how he assigns currentState to previousState and then proceeds to interpolate between essentially one game object.

Copying whole game state every update is going to put a significant performance cost on me, I'm sure. Is it normal in gamedev for other languages? I'm quite professional with JS, but have no gamedev experience with other languages. Usually copying large objects (and game state is obviously large) is a heavy operation and doing it every update (render or physics) seems bad. Also I'm going to store my objects inside QuadTree. Does that mean I'm going to copy all my objects and QuadTree every frame?

Currently I'm storing all info inside corresponding objects. My bullets have x and y and this works well. Copying gamestate will require me to split state from objects, and then, on render, go to manually update every moved object coordinates. Instead of "myBullet.x += speed", i'll have to do: myBulletState.x += speed; and later myBullet.x = myBulletState.x; // In a separate place. This is unusual and I don't see any of this "code duplication" in all the gamedev tutorials. They usually do mybullet.x += speed; and say it's done.



I realize I can switch to semi-ECS and divide between entities/components and do all that stuff, but this seems a bit overkill.
What is your way with fixed timestep and are there useful patterns/utilities?
Maybe you have tutorials on hand that go beyond "fixed timestep is this, and I leave state interpolation as your homework"?

For interpolation to work, you just need the previous and "current" state.
So what stops you from just doing pos.previous.position = pos.current.position; at the start of your movement tick?

It's important to understand that your questions have very little to do with fixed vs variable timestep. Your questions have to do with (performance-related) patterns between different languages (C/C++ and Javascript).
Copy-by-value: Structs and Arrays

If I'm wrong and it's not copied, then it's strange how he assigns
currentState to previousState and then proceeds to interpolate between
essentially one game object.

Not strange. Just that he's writing code in C / C++, in which structs are treated as value types, hence assignment is by value, just like say assigning a Number variable / property in Javascript. It's a massive benefit that I wish we had in JS; there are some future plans for this. For now, we hack.
In Javascript, any object type is assigned by reference, i.e. a pointer to the original value is copied, not the actual value. However, fast by-value copying can be done through using arrays (see below), a common pattern in games and graphics.

Copying whole game state every update is going to put a significant performance cost on me, I'm sure. Is it normal in gamedev for other languages? I'm quite professional with JS, but have no gamedev experience with other languages. Usually copying large objects (and game state is obviously large) is a heavy operation and doing it every update (render or physics) seems bad.

Right, it's not a requirement, and it will always incur some overhead, but in recent years we've realised through the influence of pure functional programming that this is the safest way to operate on state, thereby avoiding painful, hard-to-trace bugs in complex projects. It's best practice in the professional games industry. However, it's up to you.
Fast block-copying of data exists in JS these days, much like C's memcpy: Array.copyWithin() which is also usable on TypedArray (which is even faster). Alternatively for Array, you can guarantee the use of 31-bit SMIs (small integers) in a regular Array, and represent all your data that way. You can google "V8 SMI" for more info on why SMIs are desirable and how to use them.

Currently I'm storing all info inside corresponding objects. My bullets have x and y and this works well. Copying gamestate will require me to split state from objects, and then, on render, go to manually update every moved object coordinates. Instead of "myBullet.x += speed", i'll have to do:

Right, and in pure ECS, objects are always treated as pure data, not as typical OOP-style "objects as a combination of data and methods". I'd advise dropping the classic OOP approach in the context of entities, if you want high performance over many objects. Try this:
const X = 0;
const Y = 1;
const XY_COMPONENTS = 2; //X + Y = 2 components.
const ENTITIES_COUNT = 4;

//if you treat this as interleaved, it is XYXYXYXY, else it is XXXXYYYY -- index accordingly!
let positions = new Uint32Array(ENTITIES_COUNT * XY_COMPONENTS);

If using ES6 classes, make your entity-specific methods static (no local member data), and pass into them discrete objects or better yet, indices into the positions array (see below).
At the end of it all, you're going to need to represent your entities' data as array of some homogenous type, usually Uint32 or Uint64, if you want these copies to be fast.
Object Pools
Assuming you keep using JS objects rather than a large array of positions:
let stateNew = pool.retrieveNextFreeState();

//update each property, X, Y, etc. on that state in JS style (because we can't copy a whole struct by value)
copyValues(stateOld, stateNew);

pool.retireOldState(stateOld);

An object pool is used here, otherwise you're stuck creating new positions every frame, which means unnecessary allocation and GC overheads. Of course this means you need to implement or include (as a library) a performant object pool.
Important to avoid GC (garbage collection): Pools are based on some kind of array, stack or queue (all of which can be represented by JS Array), which usually implies modifying the length of the array you use as your object pool can also incur GC, via either push() / pop() / shift() / unshift(), or by adding new elements via [i], or by setting the length property. To avoid GC, implement this by pre-allocating the pool Array at a certain length and never modify that length; the downside is you must search through the full-sized array for the next free object or index.
You can pre-allocate a large Array (of SMIs) or TypedArray and have all your object data interleaved, like so:
const X = 0;
const Y = 1;
const XY_COMPONENTS = 2; //X + Y = 2 components.
const ENTITIES_COUNT = 4;

//if you treat this as interleaved, it is XYXYXYXY, else it is XXXXYYYY -- index accordingly!
let positions = new Uint32Array(ENTITIES_COUNT * XY_COMPONENTS);
let entityIndexNew = pool.retrieveNextFreeStateIndex();    

copyValuesByIndex(entityIndexOld, entityIndexNew); //to copy both X and Y for each entity.

So now your object pool will track available indices into this large array of values, rather than tracking JS object references (hopefully that's clear).
The benefit here is you are not constantly allocating (via either new or something = { ... }) and thereby incurring GC at runtime.
Conclusion
If you want the performance-centric approach, apply all the above lessons (array(s) of data + pool of data indices).
If you just want to keep it simple for now and focus on your game logic, either (a) accept the overhead of allocating new object copies every frame or (b) at the very least, store these objects in a simple pool which, even if it does incur some GC overhead through use of push() / pop(), at least avoids you allocating hundreds of new game objects every single frame for making copies.

It looks like I have to gradually move to more performant solution, starting from doing separate "state object" and deep copying it every update and ending with "data" array+object pools.
It's not clear why I need separate data array, I guess it doesn't matter if I copy bullet.x value or index to bullet.x ?
Or do you mean that in my "object pool" I store index to bullet and in data array it's bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.rotation, bullet.color, bullet.stuff etc?
Also it's not clear how do I store strings and other non-number data, but I get the idea, thanks for the comprehensive answer

@Fen1kz Yes, a gradual migration makes sense. "Or do you mean..." -- yes, that's what I mean: Data array vs indices-into-that-data-array in pool. You could have multiple data arrays but I suggest one -- whether interleaved or not -- because this reduces the number of CPU cache-misses you are likely to encounter as you move through several large arrays located in different parts of memory. Re strings, sure, but remember that almost everything important in games is numeric, i.e. that which drives engine performance. Keep strings elsewhere, don't involve them in performance-critical sections.

Storing interleaved non-homogenous numeric data: TypedArray sits on an underlying buffer of bytes (using platform-specified endianness IIRC). We can create a view of any type over this buffer e.g. a view of type Uint64 over our Uint32 array in my answer, and thereby pull X and Y out of that array as a single 64-bit value rather than 2 32-bit ones. This really speeds up code, especially with Uint64. I suggest spending time understanding TypedArrays & views. Creating views uses new, so do it at startup.
